# question about the compact space

Tags: general-topology

- Let ‎‎$‎(X,\tau(A))‎, ‎(X,\tau‎)‎‎$ ‎,‎‎be ‎compact ‎spaces. ‎**Is ‎‎$‎(‎X, (\tau(A ^{c}))‎$ ‎compact ‎space?‎**

We use ‎ ‎$ \{‎O‎_{i}‎\cup ‎(U‎_{i} ‎\cap (A^{c} ‎)‎‎)  ‎:‎ O‎_{i},U‎_{i} \in \tau,  i ‎\in I\} ‎$ ‎as a ‎‎‎‎$‎\tau(A^{c})$- ‎cover ‎for ‎‎$‎X‎$‎ and  we use ‎‎$  ‎\{ ‎O‎_{i}  : i ‎‎‎\in I‎‎‎\}‎ $ or $  ‎\{ ‎U‎_{i}  : i ‎‎‎\in I‎‎‎\}‎ $ ‎as a ‎‎‎‎$‎\tau$ - ‎cover ‎for ‎‎$‎X‎$.

- must we use exactly the open sets $U_i$and $O_i$ to show ‎‎$‎(‎X, (\tau(A ^{c}))‎$  is ‎compact ‎space?
- Does the problem need another condition to solve?
- $(\tau(A)$ is the simple extension topology  $\tau$ by A)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Oh, I've not seen that notation before.

Comment: @Noah: It boils down to the collection of sets $U\cup(V\cap A)$ for $U,V\in\tau$.

Answer (score 0):

> Let $(X,\tau(A)), (X,\tau)$, be compact spaces. Is $(X, \tau(A ^{c}))$ compact space?

If $(X,\tau)$ is any compact Hausdorff  space and $A$ is any open but not closed subset of $X$ then $\tau(A)=A$, so $(X,\tau(A))$ is compact. Suppose to the contrary that the space $(X, \tau(A ^{c}))$ is compact. Then the identity map from $(X, \tau(A ^{c}))$ to
$(X,\tau)$ is continuous, so $A ^{c}\in\tau$, a contradiction.